# Python: Remove division decimal

Tags: python, decimal, division

I have made a program that divides numbers and then returns the number, But the thing is that when it returns the number it has a decimal like this:

```
2.0
```

But I want it to give me:

```
2
```

so is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: you can also use integer division with `//` that always give a int, for example `1//2` that give `0`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can call `int()` on the end result:

```
>>> int(2.0)
2
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '68.0'

Comment: @Kyrie You can do `int(float('68.0'))`

Comment: @TerryA It won't work in case of `int(1.9999999999999999999)`, how can I just remove the decimals?

Comment: @Bear `math.floor(1.9999999999999999999)`

Answer (score 35):

When a number as a decimal it is usually a [`float`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) in Python.

If you want to remove the decimal and keep it an integer ([`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)). You can call the `int()` method on it like so...

```
>>> int(2.0)
2
```

However, `int` rounds *down* so...

```
>>> int(2.9)
2
```

If you want to round to the nearest integer you can use [`round`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> round(2.9)
3.0
>>> round(2.4)
2.0
```

And then call `int()` on that:

```
>>> int(round(2.9))
3
>>> int(round(2.4))
2
```

Comment: What if it is a large number?

Comment: @Jeff Why don't you check yourself? Python does not have a problem with the size of numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that a bit after I posted. For whatever reason, I thought that a unix date format would be too large a number, but I was wrong!

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do like below

```
# p and q are the numbers to be divided
if p//q==p/q:
    print(p//q)
else:
    print(p/q)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me solve a different but related issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a math function `modf()` that will break this up as well.

```
import math

print("math.modf(3.14159) : ", math.modf(3.14159))
```

will output a tuple:
`math.modf(3.14159) : (0.14159, 3.0)`

This is useful if you want to keep both the whole part and decimal for reference like:

`decimal, whole = math.modf(3.14159)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> int(2.0)
```

You will get the answer as 2

Comment: What does this add that isn't already present in the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
def division(a, b):
    return a / b if a % b else a // b
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
if val % 1 == 0:
    val = int(val)

else:
    val = float(val)
```

This worked for me.

How it works: if the remainder of the quotient of val and 1 is 0, val has to be an integer and can, therefore, be declared to be int without having to worry about losing decimal numbers.

Compare these two situations:

A:

```py
val = 12.00

if val % 1 == 0:
    val = int(val)
else:
    val = float(val)

print(val)
```

In this scenario, the output is 12, because 12.00 divided by 1 has the remainder of 0. With this information we know, that val doesn't have any decimals and we can declare val to be int.

B:

```py
val = 13.58

if val % 1 == 0:
    val = int(val)
else:
    val = float(val)

print(val)
```

This time the output is 13.58, because when val is divided by 1 there is a remainder (0.58) and therefore val is declared to be a float.

By just declaring the number to be an int (without testing the remainder) decimal numbers will be cut off.

This way there are no zeros in the end and no other than the zeros will be ignored.

Comment: @jayveesea Thanks for the tip, I'm still new on the site and in programming overall.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways to remove decimal places in Python,

1. **Using the [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function**
2. **Using the [trunc()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.trunc) function in [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#module-math) library**
3. **Using string formatting and methods**

   1. **Using `%d` placeholder**
   2. **Using split() function**
4. **Using the round() function**

---

## 1. Using the int() function

[int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) is a Python [Built-in Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) function.

```py
>>> number = 2.0
>>> number
2.0
>>> number = int(2.0)
2
>>> type(number)
<class 'int'>
```

---

## 2. Using the trunc() function in math library

[trunc()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.trunc) function in [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#module-math) library.

```py
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> number = 2.0
>>> number
2.0
>>> number = math.trunc(2.0)
2
>>> type(number)
<class 'int'>
```

---

## 3. Using string formatting and methods

Please note:- Everything returned in this section is of type `str`.

#### 1. Using %d placeholder

Format the string with the `%d` placeholder

```py
>>> number = 2.0
>>> number
2.0
>>> number = '%d'%number
>>> number
'2'
>>> type(number)
<class 'str'>
```

#### 2. Using split() function

[split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function is a [string](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#text-sequence-type-str) method.

```py
>>> number = 2.0
>>> number
2.0
>>> number=str(number).split('.')[0]
>>> number
'2'
>>> type(number)
<class 'str'>
```

---

## 4. Using the round() function

[round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) is a [Built-in Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions).

```py
>>> number = 2.0
>>> number
2.0
>>> number = round(number)
>>> number
2
>>> type(number)
<class 'int'>
```

---

References:-

- [Remove Decimal Places in Python](https://java2blog.com/remove-decimal-places-python/#Using_the_round_function)
- [How to Remove Decimal in Python](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-remove-decimal-in-python)
- [How to truncate Python values to a whole, integer number?](https://kodify.net/python/math/truncate-integers/)
- [How to remove all decimals from a number using Python?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-all-decimals-from-a-number-using-python/)