# How can I remove ".0" of float numbers?

Tags: floating-point, int, python-3.5

Say I have a float number. If it is an integer (e.g. 1.0, 9.0, 36.0), I want to remove the ".0 (the decimal point and zero)" and write to stdout. For example, the result will be 1, 9, 36. If the float number is a rational number such as 2.5335 and 95.5893, I want the output to be as it was inputted, meaning 2.5335 and 95.5893. Is there a smart way to do this?

Only whether the number has .0 or other digits at decimal places does matter. I can say my question is this: how can I know whether or not a float number is actually an integer?

I want to use this to decide directory names. For example, if I input 9.0 and 2.45, make two directories, dir9 and dir2.45.

Comment: "if the float number is a rational number such as 2.5335 and 95.5893, I want the output to be as it was inputted." What do you mean by this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Remove division decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651384/python-remove-division-decimal)

Comment: Do you trust Python is correct when it tells you a certain `1.0` does not have zeroes all the way, or do you want to check only the first few digits, as in your examples?

Comment: Are you aware that `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` (and other fun consequences of floats being binary rather than decimal)?

Comment: I understand 0.1 may not be exactly 0.1, but why cannot 1.0 be precisely 1.0?
That 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 does not seem to be relevant to this question. Could you explain how it is related to my question?

Comment: You have to be more clear about the phrase "I want the output to be as it was inputted", assuming that the input is a decimal rational number. For instance, `123456789.123456769 == 123456789.123456783` is true for my installation (both these floats are printed as `123456789.12345678`). On another note, for large "integer" floats, you'll lose digits before the decimal point (for my installation, `int(123456789123456789.0) - 123456789123456789 == -5`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a function to format your numbers the way you want them:

```
def formatNumber(num):
  if num % 1 == 0:
    return int(num)
  else:
    return num
```

For example:

```
formatNumber(3.11111)
```

returns

`3.11111`

---

`formatNumber(3.0)`

returns

`3`

Answer (score 11):

you can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```py
>>> "%g" % 1.1
'1.1'
```

```py
>>> "%g" % 1.0
'1'
```

Answer (score 8):

You can combine the 2 previous answers :

```py
formatNumber = lambda n: n if n%1 else int(n)
```

```
>>>formatNumber(5)
5

>>>formatNumber(5.23)
5.23

>>>formatNumber(6.0)
6
```

Comment: It's possible to define 
`formatNumber = lambda n: int(n) if isinstance(n,float) and n.is_integer() else n`

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with fstrings like

```py
print(f'{1.0:g},{1.2:g}')  # Output: 1,1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = 5.0
if float(num) == int(num):
    num = int(num)
```

Output: 5

Comment: This works, but I think it would be better to write this as a function.

Answer (score -3):

just type
int(number)
example :

```
int(3.0)
```

returns

```
3
```

Comment: unfortunately, int(3.5) also returns 3 which the OP specifically does not want to have happen.