# Remove ".0" from float series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with values such as 164684564.0 (type is float 64)

I just want to remove all the ".0"s from these numbers

```
"{:g}".format
```

did not work
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38283006/16796767
did not work either

Another thing: I don't want to convert in scientific numbers (I did it once but I don't remember the code I used).
I also tried something else which occurred "cannot use this on series" error

A magical working answer would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a string or integer? `"{:g}.format` isn't code that will do what you want. Please post the required [mre] that reproduces the exact problem you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method astype from the class DataFrame:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]], columns=['Pop'])

>> print(df)
   Pop
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0

>> df = df.astype(int)

>> print(df)
   Pop
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cast your data frame to int use:

```
int_df = df.astype(int)
```