# I can not convert the currency conversion, using Forex, to the integer for removing the decimal division, in Python

Tags: python, pandas, integer, currency

I am using Pandas to read a CSV file, Forex to convert the currency to other currencies and the integer mode (`int`) to remove the decimal division, but it gave an error.

Sample CSV:

```
Item,Price (BRL)
Dining devices,100
Dishwasher,600
Electric shower,200
Fridge,1600
Induction cooktop cooker,1800
Kitchen cabinet,900
Kit pans,200
Microwave,700
```

And:

```py
import pandas as pd
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv

cc = CurrencyRates()

cad = cc.convert('BRL', 'CAD', 1)
nzd = cc.convert('BRL', 'NZD', 1)
usd = cc.convert('BRL', 'USD', 1)

c = read_csv('data/purchases.csv')
c.loc["Total"] = c.sum()
c["Item"].values[-1] = "  "
```

I replaced `round` with `int`, as suggested from [Python: Remove division decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651384/python-remove-division-decimal):

```
c["USD"] = int((((c["Price (BRL)"] * usd) / 2) * 2 + 1))
c["CAD"] = int((((c["Price (BRL)"] * cad) / 2) * 2 + 1))
c["NZD"] = int((((c["Price (BRL)"] * nzd) / 2) * 2 + 1))
c
```

It gave an error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c0af80ffd537> in <module>
     14 c["Item"].values[-1] = "  "
     15 
---> 16 c["USD"] = int((((c["Price (BRL)"] * usd) / 2) * 2 + 1))
     17 c["CAD"] = int((((c["Price (BRL)"] * cad) / 2) * 2 + 1))
     18 c["NZD"] = int((((c["Price (BRL)"] * nzd) / 2) * 2 + 1))

~/GitLab/Gustavo/global/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    139         if len(self) == 1:
    140             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 141         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    142 
    143     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Comment: You can't convert an entire series to a single `int`.  Instead, your have to `apply` or `map` int to the elements of the series.  With that hint, I expect you can fix the code.

Comment: @Prune *have to* is very strong i think; no need to `apply` or `map`, answer is below with `astype(int)`. But if you meant something else, pardon me.

Comment: Good point; yes, that's a better solution.  "You can" is phrase more appropriate than "you have to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most operations on a series are vectorized, i.e. `pd.Series([n for n in ...]) + 1` means `pd.Series([n + 1 for n in ...])`, that is not the case of `int()`, which attemps to convert the full `pandas.Series` object to an integer. That doesn’t work.

Instead you want a pandas way of casting each element to int, try [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for example

```
>>> df['Price (BRL)'] * usd
0     20.0
1    120.0
2     40.0
3    320.0
4    360.0
5    180.0
6     40.0
7    140.0
Name: Price (BRL), dtype: float64
>>> (df['Price (BRL)'] * usd).astype(int)
0     20
1    120
2     40
3    320
4    360
5    180
6     40
7    140
Name: Price (BRL), dtype: int64
```

I suppose your multiplication/division by 2 and adding 1 is in order to round to nearest. Casting directly to `int` does indeed round down. Instead you can use [`pd.Series.round()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
>>> pd.Series([.6]).astype(int)
0    0
dtype: int64
>>> pd.Series([.6]).round().astype(int)
0    1
dtype: int64
```

So probably what you’re trying to achieve is `(df['Price (BRL)'] * usd).round().astype(int)`